# Android Certificate and Update

Tags: android

I have an app I want to update I have the code, and a certificate but not keystore. Is it possible to create a keystore with all this in order to update it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html?

Answer (score 0):

In order to update an app, you must sign it with the same key with which it was originally signed. Otherwise, you will need to publish the "update" as a brand new app.

Comment: Event with the certificate I cannot create a new keystore?

Comment: @jcaruso What do you mean by "certificate"? What kind of file is it?

Comment: @jcaruso Is it the same certificate that the app was originally signed with?

Comment: @jcaruso I'm not sure. I suggest reading the docs for `jarsigner` to see if you can get it to work with your certificate.